# Pasar un array de palabras a un string

Tags: javascript, array, string, arraylist, ecmascript-6

Lo que sucede aquí es que estoy tratando de reforzar mis conocimientos en `JS`, practicando ciertos desafíos en [codewars](https://www.codewars.com/). El desafío que estoy haciendo ahora se trata de los siguiente:

"Escriba una función que tome una cadena de una o más palabras y devuelva la misma cadena, pero con las cinco o más letras invertidas. Las cadenas aprobadas consistirán solo de letras y espacios. Los espacios se incluirán solo cuando haya más de una palabra presente."

Ejemplos:

1. spinWords( "Hey fellow warriors" ) => returns "Hey wollef sroirraw"
2. spinWords( "This is a test") => returns "This is a test"
3. spinWords( "This is another test" )=> returns "This is rehtona test"

Lo que hice para cumplir esa condición es meter cada palabra en un mismo array y cada una de esas meterlas en un array separado por letras. Mi problema es que `codewars` a la hora de probar mi función devuelve `""` y creo que el problema esta en el pasaje del array a string pero nose bien que puede ser. Si alguien me explica porque sucede esto se lo agradeceria.

Lo que se espera en la salida seria la misma cadena de texto pero con las palabras invertidas cuyas letras sean iguales a 5 o más.

```js
function spinWords(str){
    let splittedWord = str.split(" "), arr = [], result;

    for(let i = 0; i < splittedWord; i++){

        arr.push(splittedWord[i].split(""));

        if(arr[i].length >= 5){
            arr[i].reverse();
            
        }

    }

    result = arr.join(" ");
    return result;
 
}
```

Comment: Pero cuales son las salidas correctas que esperas de tu código? Los ejemplos no están claros: la entrada es: Esta es otra prueba  y el resultado es Esto es la prueba de rehtona. De dónde sale eso? En el enunciado dice : pero con las cinco o más letras invertidas, cuales son esas cinco o más letras?

Comment: A lo que se refiere es que en la salida lo que se espera es que las palabras que tengan 5 letras o mas pero con las letras invertidas. Mira el ejemplo "Esta es una prueba", se mantiene igual porque ninguna de las palabras tiene 5 o mas letras. El ejemplo 3, que fue mi error, esta mal porque esta traducido del ingles "This is another test" donde another tiene mas de 5 letras por lo tanto sale invertida como rehtona.

Comment: prueba tiene 6 letras

Comment: Lo siento es la por la traduccion al español. Los ejemplos en realidad vienen del ingles donde prueba es "test" y test tiene 4 letras. Perdon por la confusion ya lo arregle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu código tiene 4 errores:

1. En el for te falta llamar la propiedad length del arreglo
2. `arr[i].reverse()` retorna un arreglo invertido que debe guardarse en algún lugar, lo cambié a `arr[i] = arr[i].reverse();`
3. Haces `result = arr.join(" ")`, arr contiene varios arreglos por lo que tienes que recorrerlo y hacer un join por cada uno.
4. `join("")` no tiene que llevar espacio

```js
function spinWords(str){
    let splittedWord = str.split(" "), arr = [], result = "";

    for(let i = 0; i < splittedWord.length; i++){

        arr.push(splittedWord[i].split(""));

        if(arr[i].length >= 5){
            arr[i] = arr[i].reverse();
            
        }

    }
    
    arr.forEach(p => {
     result = result + " " + p.join("");
    });
    return result;
 
}

console.log(spinWords("hola mundos"))
```